# The Fermat numbers are defined as $F_{n} = 2^{2^n} + 1$, for all n $\geq$ 0. Prove that $F_{n} = (F_{0} * F_{1} * F_{2} * ... * F_{n-1}) + 2 $

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I know that this should be a proof by induction, and my hunch is strong induction, but I am unsure about how to go about this.

In my base case, I made sure that the proposition held for n = 0, n = 1, and n = 2 before moving onto my inductive step.

Am I trying to show that $2^{2^{(n+1)}} + 1$ = ($2^{2^0}+ 1 * ... *2^{2^{n-1}}+1*2^{2^n}+1)+2 $?

Comment: I think this has been asked here before. What should help if we denote $F(n):=2^{2^n}+1$ : $$F_{n+1}=(F_n-1)^2+1$$

Comment: Going forward, for *generic* problems of this type, the first step is $~\color{red}{\text{Elbow Grease}},~$ using scratch paper.  For example, with this problem, you (for example) let $n$ be each element in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  For each such element, you compute $F_n$ both by the formula and by the assertion.  If they match in each case, expand your intuition by examining the data to determine **why** they match.  Then, you are ready to try a proof, perhaps by some form of induction.